# How can I create excel charts with different shapes?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to build a stacked chart with the stack in the shape of an outline of a person. How can i do this?

Comment: What type of stacked chart? A full-height stack or regular stack? Interesting question - I can't think of any way to do it off the top of my head, but there's probably a way. Do you want the person shapes to all be the same height?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Select the shape (e.g. clipart or shapes) you want inserted, and copy it.
2. Select the chart series you want "shaped", and paste your shape.
3. If you want multiple stacked series formated, you can copy and paste the same or different shapes.  You can also select individual points in the series and change theirs (e.g. top 3 left stacks).

The new shape will replace the pre-existing, Excel shape.

EDIT: After looking at the original image, it appeared that the figures were super-imposed on the existing Excel chart columns-but that was an illusion (the photo just had a column-like background).  So I modified the chart to show a number of image-type options.

[image: Stacked figures]

Comment: After answering, I feel compelled to point out that just because you can do this in Excel, doesn't necessarily mean you should.  The images become distracting and more difficult to convey the message you're trying to produce.  For more thoughts on that, you can search the term "Chart Junk".